# Progress bar Error while uploading on FTP - Android

Tags: java, android, apache, ftp, android-asynctask

i have this code in Background in Async class:

```
FileInputStream InputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(DBToUploadFromInternalStorage.getPath()));

                                          if(x!=2){
                                             try{
                                                 con.storeFile("/"+Email+"/PilotLogbookDB.itb", InputStream);
                                                 bytesAvailable = InputStream.available();
                                                 bytesRead = InputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                                                 while (bytesRead > 0)
                                                 {  
                                                     progress+=bytesRead;
                                                     publishProgress((int)((progress*100)/(DBToUploadFromInternalStorage.getPath().length())));

                                                 }//end of while statement
                                                 publishProgress(100); 

                                             }
                                             catch(Exception e){
                                                 e.printStackTrace();
                                                 x=2;
                                             }
                                         }
                                             InputStream.close();
                                             if(x !=2){
                                             BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new 
                                             File(getFilesDir()+File.separator+"Cloud Version.itb")));
                                             bufferedWriter.write(String.valueOf(Version));
                                             bufferedWriter.close();
                                             FileInputStream InputStream_ = new FileInputStream(new File(CloudVersionSysForRestore.getPath()));
                                             if(x!=2){
                                             try{
                                                 con.storeFile("/"+Email+"/Cloud Version.itb", InputStream_);
                                             }
                                             catch(Exception e){
                                                 e.printStackTrace();
                                                 x=2;
                                             }
                                             }
                                             InputStream_.close();
                                             }
```

The problem is that the file si uploading but the progress bar remains on 0. After file upload, on post execution, the dialog is dismissing so it works

I also have a error on `bytesRead = InputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);`in Logcat

LogCat Output:

```
08-02 02:36:32.884: W/System.err(27519): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-02 02:36:32.894: W/System.err(27519):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.read(IoBridge.java:427)
08-02 02:36:32.894: W/System.err(27519):    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:179)
08-02 02:36:32.904: W/System.err(27519):    at com.itbstudios.pilotlogbook.PilotLogbook_main$AsyncSenderSync.doInBackground(PilotLogbook_main.java:7061)
08-02 02:36:32.904: W/System.err(27519):    at com.itbstudios.pilotlogbook.PilotLogbook_main$AsyncSenderSync.doInBackground(PilotLogbook_main.java:1)
08-02 02:36:32.914: W/System.err(27519):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
08-02 02:36:32.914: W/System.err(27519):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
08-02 02:36:32.924: W/System.err(27519):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
08-02 02:36:32.924: W/System.err(27519):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
08-02 02:36:32.934: W/System.err(27519):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
08-02 02:36:32.934: W/System.err(27519):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
08-02 02:36:32.934: W/System.err(27519):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
```

I'm trying to upload on FTP using Async and Apache Lib. v 3.3

FULL Async Class:

```
private final class AsyncSenderSync extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, Integer> {

        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable;
         int progress=0;
         byte[] buffer;
         int bufferSize = 512;
         File DataDirectory = Environment.getDataDirectory();
         String DataPath = "//data//com.itbstudios.pilotlogbook//databases//PilotLogbookDB";
         File DBToUploadFromInternalStorage = new File(DataDirectory, DataPath);

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            pd = new ProgressDialog(PilotLogbook_main.this);
            pd.setTitle("Syncing Data");
            pd.setMessage("Please wait, data is syncing...");
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.setIndeterminate(false);


            pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            pd.setProgress(0);
            pd.setMax(100);
            pd.incrementProgressBy((int)((progress*100)/(DBToUploadFromInternalStorage.length())));



            if(!pd.isShowing())
                pd.show();
            else
                {
                    pd.cancel();
                    pd.dismiss();
                }
        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
            int x = 0;
            DBSettingsHelper.open();
            DBHelper.open();
            File DataDirectory = Environment.getDataDirectory();
            Cursor cursor = DBSettingsHelper.getEmailbyRowId(1);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            Cursor cursor_version = DBSettingsHelper.getCloudVersionbyRowId(1);
            cursor_version.moveToFirst();

            long Version = DBSettingsHelper.CloudStatus(cursor_version);

            String Email = DBSettingsHelper.EmailStatus(cursor);



            File DatabaseInternalStorageDirectory  = Environment.getDataDirectory();
            String FinalRestorePointPathForDB = "//data//com.itbstudios.pilotlogbook//databases//PilotLogbookDB";
            File  EmptyFileForRestore = new File(DatabaseInternalStorageDirectory, FinalRestorePointPathForDB);


            FTPClient con = null;




            try
            {

                con = new FTPClient();
                con.setConnectTimeout(300000);
                con.setDataTimeout(300000);

                con.connect("host",21);

                if (con.login("user", "pass"))
                {
                    con.enterLocalPassiveMode(); // important!
                    con.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);


                    boolean directoryExists = con.changeWorkingDirectory(Email);



                            File CloudVersionSysForRestore = new File(getFilesDir()+File.separator+"Cloud Version.itb");

                                    try {
                                        CloudVersionSysForRestore.createNewFile();





                                        OutputStream OutstreamCloud = new FileOutputStream(new File(CloudVersionSysForRestore.getPath()));




                                        boolean resultCloud = con.retrieveFile("/"+Email+"/Cloud Version.itb", OutstreamCloud);
                                        OutstreamCloud.close();


                                         BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new 
                                                 File(getFilesDir()+File.separator+"Cloud Version.itb")));
                                         String read;
                                         StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("");

                                         while((read = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                                             builder.append(read);
                                         }
                                         bufferedReader.close();
                                         long getintfromstring = Long.parseLong(builder.toString());

                                         if(getintfromstring<Version){

                                             FileInputStream InputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(DBToUploadFromInternalStorage.getPath()));

                                          if(x!=2){
                                             try{
                                                 con.storeFile("/"+Email+"/PilotLogbookDB.itb", InputStream);
                                                 bytesAvailable = InputStream.available();
                                                 bytesRead = InputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                                                 while (bytesRead > 0)
                                                 {  
                                                     progress+=bytesRead;
                                                     publishProgress((int)((progress*100)/(DBToUploadFromInternalStorage.getPath().length())));

                                                 }//end of while statement
                                                 publishProgress(100); 

                                             }
                                             catch(Exception e){
                                                 e.printStackTrace();
                                                 x=2;
                                             }
                                         }
                                             InputStream.close();
                                             if(x !=2){
                                             BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new 
                                             File(getFilesDir()+File.separator+"Cloud Version.itb")));
                                             bufferedWriter.write(String.valueOf(Version));
                                             bufferedWriter.close();
                                             FileInputStream InputStream_ = new FileInputStream(new File(CloudVersionSysForRestore.getPath()));
                                             if(x!=2){
                                             try{
                                                 con.storeFile("/"+Email+"/Cloud Version.itb", InputStream_);
                                             }
                                             catch(Exception e){
                                                 e.printStackTrace();
                                                 x=2;
                                             }
                                             }
                                             InputStream_.close();
                                             }

                                         }







                                        if(getintfromstring>Version){



                                         OutputStream OutstreamDatabase = new FileOutputStream(new File(EmptyFileForRestore.getPath()));
                                         if(x!=2){
                                         try{
                                             con.retrieveFile("/"+Email+"/PilotLogbookDB.itb", OutstreamDatabase);
                                         }
                                         catch(Exception e){
                                             e.printStackTrace();
                                             x=2;
                                         }
                                         }
                                         OutstreamDatabase.close();
                                         if(x!=2)
                                         DBSettingsHelper.updateCloudVersion(1,getintfromstring);


                                        }



                                        CloudVersionSysForRestore.delete();

                                        DBSettingsHelper.close();
                                        DBHelper.close();
                                        x = 1;

                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                        Log.w("timeout", "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
                                        x=2;
                                    }



                    }
                con.logout();
                con.disconnect();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.w("timeout", "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
                x=2;

            }


            return x;
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values)
           {
               super.onProgressUpdate(values);
               pd.setProgress(values[0]);
           }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);


                if(result == 2)
                {


                    final AlertDialog.Builder builder___ = new AlertDialog.Builder(PilotLogbook_main.this);




                        builder___.setTitle("Error!");
                        builder___.setMessage(Html.fromHtml(
                                "Something went wrong (501)"
                                + "<br><br>"
                                + "Cloud error please try again. If you'll see this error again please report it at:"
                                + "<br>"
                                +"<b>support@itbstudios.tk</b>"

                                 ))
                               .setCancelable(false)
                               .setNegativeButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                    pd.cancel();
                                    pd.dismiss();

                                }
                               });






                        final AlertDialog alert___ = builder___.create();
                        alert___.show();
                } 


                pd.dismiss();
                InitialReport();



        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need in override onProgressUpdate() in asynctask and update your progress dialog.

To update the progress bar while uploading a file, you need to do something like this:

@Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        --
        --
        long progress=(long)(downloadedSize*100/totalSize);
        publishProgress("" + progress);
        }

```
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
     Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC",progress[0]);
     mProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
}

  protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
  }
```

Comment: I had try but dosen't help... EDIT: I added the full async to the question

Comment: so.. it looks like if i delete store command it is progressing but no upload
if i add store it is not progressing but is uploading